# Take value out of std::optional

Tags: c++, c++17, option-type, stdoptional

How do you actually take a value out of optional? Meaning take ownership of the value inside the `std::optional` and replace it with `std::nullopt` (or swap it with another value)?

In Rust for example you could `.unwrap` your `Option` or do something like `foo.take().unwrap()`. I'm trying to do something like that with C++ `optional`s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`operator*`/`value()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*) returns a reference to the value held by the `optional`, so you can simply use `std::move` to move it to a temporary variable

```
std::optional<std::string> opt = "abc";
// "take" the contained value by calling operator* on a rvalue to optional
auto taken = *std::move(opt);
```

This will invoke the rvalue reference overload of `operator*()` of the `optional,` which returns an rvalue reference to the contained value.

You can also directly perform `std::move` on the return value of the `operator*()` of the lvalue `optional`, which will convert the lvalue reference of the contained value into an rvalue

```
auto taken = std::move(*opt);
```

Comment: `opt` still contains (moved-from) value after that. Ideally you should follow-up with `.reset()`. Also, tangential, but `*std::move(opt)` and `std::move(*opt)` are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way in C++ to replace a value and return the old, like `mem::replace` in Rust, is `std::exchange`.

So:

```
std::exchange(o, std::nullopt).value();
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G7faK9rxj

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain why this works? I'm super new to C++ and two things that I don't understand - 1) why does exchange work here and 2) why does .value() not return a reference instead?

Comment: `std::exchange` copies the value of the first argument (`o`), then assigns the second argument to the first (`o = std::nullopt`) and then returns the copy, i.e. the old value of the first argument (what was in `o` before). It returns by value. Because `std::exchange(o, std::nullopt)` is a temporary, when you call `.value()` on it, you get an rvalue reference, and so assignment will move from it.